# Can't style 2 carousel even with different id

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to this so please bear with me.

This is my snippet:

https://liveweave.com/WJav5F

My expected behavior is the first carousel (id carousel) have full width of the container, no stretch or any kind of distortions.

The current behavior is if the second carousel is render correctly, the first carousel is not span to the width of the container.

I tried to use the id selector like this but it doesn't work:

```
    #carousel .carousel-inner .item img{

       min-width:100%;

        }

#myCarousel .carousel .item img {   //comment this block and the id carousel  renders correct (no distortion) but break the id myCarousel. 
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

As @Honzik Kryspin.

```
#carousel.carousel-inner .item img{

           min-width:100%;

            }

    #myCarousel.carousel .item img {    
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can work around by comment this section

```
#myCarousel .carousel .item img {   //comment this block and the id carousel  renders correct (no distortion) but break the id myCarousel. 
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

And put the code directly into img tag. Pretty suck :(

Answer (score 0):

You have space in your selector, that means it searches for `.carousel` inside `#myCarousel`. You probably want the second selector as `#myCarousel.carousel .item img`

Comment: I played around with the space like you mentioned but it doesn't work. Can you please  see the updated question and tell my why?

Comment: In the updated question you have now problem with the first selector `.carousel-inner` is nested to `#carousel` so it should be `#carousel .carousel-inner .item img`. However I am not sure what is the problem. You want the images to spread over whole width, if so remove padding on `.carousel`? Otherwise I don't understand what you mean :)